# MFC ListView: Crash when beginning an item editing (LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT)

Tags: listview, mfc, access-violation, ownerdrawn

I'm using CListView with owner-drawn items in Report mode, and now I'd like to add the functionality of editting the items (and then extend it to subitems as well). The CListView is instantiated with these parameters (LVS_REPORT guaranteed by other part of the program):

```
BOOL CMyListView::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT &cs){
    if (!CListView::PreCreateWindow(cs)) return FALSE;
    cs.style|= LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | LVS_NOLABELWRAP | LVS_EDITLABELS;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Obviously, each item in the list view is a pointer to a structure that the owner uses to draw an item when requested to. To capture the moment the list view begins the editing of an item, I'm processing the LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT notification:

```
// in list view message map
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT,OnEditBegin)
```

The problem is that the program crashes as soon as when it leaves the corresponding handler:

```
afx_msg void CMyListView::OnEditBegin(NMHDR *pNMHDR,LRESULT *pResult){
    ::Beep(1000,10); // just beep
    *pResult=TRUE; // and don't allow editing now
} // bonus feature: a crash
```

Tried to process the LVN_GETDISPINFO notification but was receiving the item information without the pointer set (maybe LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED cannot be used in combination with LVS_OWNERDATA; can't check as MSDN down when writting this question):

```
// the way item added to list view
LVITEM lvi={ LVIF_TEXT|LVIF_PARAM };
lvi.iItem=i++;
lvi.pszText=sr->jmeno; // for the "Large icons" mode
lvi.lParam=sr->param;

// LVN_GETDISPINFO notification handler
afx_msg void CMyListView::OnGetDispInfo(NMHDR *pNMHDR,LRESULT *pResult){
    NMLVDISPINFO *info=(NMLVDISPINFO *)pNMHDR;
    info->item.pszText=(LPSTR)info->item.lParam; // lParam received as unset
    *pResult=0;
}
```

Tried to switch the list view into the "Large icons" mode (where items must be represented using strings, not just pointers) but with the same result - a nice loud memory reading violation.

Using Visual Studio 2010 Express with legacy MFC6 (that is, I can't trace the MFC source to easily find out where the dog lies burried).

Any help/suggestion very appreciated, many thanks!

Kind regards,

Tomas

Comment: Is the code asserting, or, crashing?  If asserting, where?

Comment: I can not confirm this. I have code here running were pDispInfo->item.lParam is set correctly.

Comment: The code was crashing (Access violation). The past tense = abandoned this way as, carefully seeing some examples on the Internet, I figured out that this out-of-the-box functionality allows editing using an edit box only, whereas I want to show a combo box and custom editors as well. So I stopped being interested in using it, but thanks for the comments anyway :-)